# Javascript show/hide menu on scroll with a twist

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is a demo of the menu fadeIn:

[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hfnrn7xz/1/)

I am seeking some advice on a tricky show hide problem I have. So my menu fades in at a certain point using the following:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
   var d = $('#menu'); 
    if (d.offset().top > 810) {
       d.fadeIn();
    } else {
       d.stop().hide();
    }
});
```

What I need to do however is one of the links within the menu to not be hidden and show at the top of  the page and then also remain once the menu appears with the other links.

The menu displays with the following:

```
<div id="menu">

    <div class="top-bar">

        <div class="container">

            <div>
                <a href="index.php" class="top-bar-brand">MyWebsite</a>                  
            </div>

            <nav>
                <ul class="navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="">Buy Now</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Link2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Link2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Login</a></li>
                </ul>  
            </nav>    
        </div>

    </div>

</div>


#menu {
    width : 100%;
    height : auto;
    overflow: auto;
    position: fixed;
    display : none;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
    z-index: 999999;
}
```

so the link called 'Login' need to show at all times but the other links and the background color of the menu shows on the scroll and then hides again but the 'login' link remains.

Comment: can you put this problem into a jsfiddle?

Comment: The menu doesn't display with the current code... unless your page has a vertical scroll bar

Comment: @Stefan I have updated my question with a demo

Comment: @Lost Yeah if you see the menu shows anything past 810 pixels so in my demo i have added a body div to show this.

Comment: Ok now i see it's inside hidden element. You have to pull it out from hidden div firstly.

Comment: @JacobSobus that is where I am struggling to find the best approach...

Comment: In my opinion it should be outside that first div and using position: absolute; set on right corner. But this is my first thought only.

Comment: Hm. I can try that but seems a bit of a quick and dirty method?

Comment: the issue with that is that the web page is fully responsive and would not really be suited to what I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this, see if this is what you wanted
[JSfiddle updated](http://jsfiddle.net/kduqtLfw/2/)

```
    <div id="menu">

    <div class="top-bar">

        <div class="container">

            <div>
                <a href="index.php" class="top-bar-brand hideme">SchoolShare</a>                  
            </div>

            <nav>
                <ul class="navbar-right">
                    <li class="hideme"><a href="">Buy Now</a></li>
                    <li class="hideme"><a href="">Parents</a></li>
                    <li class="hideme"><a href="">Schools</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Login</a></li>
                </ul>  
            </nav>    
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
</div>

<div class="bodydiv">Scroll down</div>
```

the javascript

```
$('.hideme').hide();
$(window).scroll(function () {
   var d = $('#menu'); 
    if (d.offset().top > 810) {
       $('.hideme').fadeIn();
        $('#menu').css({'background':'rgba(255,255,255,0.9)'});
    } else {
       $('.hideme').fadeOut();
        $('#menu').css({'background':'rgba(255,255,255,0)'});
    }
});
```

the css

```
#menu {
    width : 100%;
    height : auto;
    overflow: auto;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999999;
}

.top-bar{
    width:100%;
    overflow:auto;
    height:auto;
    padding: 10px 0;
}

.top-bar-brand{
    float:left;
    font-size:18px;
    color: #2C3E50;
    display: block;
    -webkit-margin-before: 1em;
    -webkit-margin-after: 1em;
    -webkit-margin-start: 0px;
    -webkit-margin-end: 0px;
    -webkit-padding-start: 10px;
}

nav{
    float:right;    
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 4px 0 0 0;
}

.navbar-right{
}

.navbar-right ul{
    padding: 0;
    list-style:none;
}

.navbar-right li{
    display:inline-block;
    margin: 0 10px;
}

body{background-color: #ddd;}

.bodydiv{height: 2000px;}
.hideme {
    display: none;
}
#menu {
    -webkit-transition: background 500ms ease;
    -moz-transition: background 500ms ease;
    -o-transition: background 500ms ease;
    transition: background 500ms ease;
}
```

Comment: so this is almost what I want, but the logo and the background need to be hidden it is just 'login' that always shows...is that doable?

Comment: I altered the HTML, javascript and CSS so you need to apply all of it

Comment: Its all working but in a bizarre way...so all the links show initially on page load, they then disappear when you scroll and then re-appear at the showing point again.

Comment: yup thats the purpose of the `$('.hideme').hide();` add it on `document.ready` if you have one

Comment: Nice approach - not editing original html structure.

Answer (score 1):

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hfnrn7xz/9/)

Html:

```
<div id="menu">

    <div class="top-bar">

        <div class="container">

            <div>
                <a href="index.php" class="top-bar-brand">SchoolShare</a>                  
            </div>

            <nav>
                <ul class="navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="">Buy Now</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Parents</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Schools</a></li>
                </ul>  
            </nav>    
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
<a class="login" href="">Login</a>

<div class="bodydiv">Scroll down</div>
```

css:

```
    #menu {
    width : 100%;
    height : auto;
    overflow: auto;
    position: fixed;
    display : none;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
    z-index: 999998;
}

.login{
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 999998;
    top: 38px
}

.top-bar{
    width:100%;
    overflow:auto;
    height:auto;
    padding: 10px 0;
}

.top-bar-brand{
    float:left;
    font-size:18px;
    color: #2C3E50;
    display: block;
    -webkit-margin-before: 1em;
    -webkit-margin-after: 1em;
    -webkit-margin-start: 0px;
    -webkit-margin-end: 0px;
    -webkit-padding-start: 10px;
}

nav{
    float:right;    
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 4px 65px 0 0;
}

.navbar-right{
}

.navbar-right ul{
    padding: 0;
    list-style:none;
}

.navbar-right li{
    display:inline-block;
    margin: 0 10px;
}

body{background-color: #ddd;}

.bodydiv{height: 2000px;}
```

Javascript not edited.

Comment: Hi Jacob, almost there, but I need login to show and also be in the menu on the right hand side. So initially is shows at the top of the webpage, and then when you scroll down the menu background appears with the other links.

Comment: Updated :) Now it's ok i think. It's html/css edit only. Javascript version from @Roi is good also.

Comment: Its all working but in a bizarre way...so all the links show initially on page load, they then disappear when you scroll and then re-appear at the showing point again.

Comment: I don't have any fading javascript :D It's interesting what are you saing now. On my fiddle everything works good. Maybe some browser problem?